# What can I do to optimize my web page for a mobile phone, specifically the iPhone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone

So I purchased myself an iPhone ... everybody has one ... so I figured I'd **see** what the big deal was.  To my surprise ... and overall skepticism ... I must say that I am **very** impressed with the iPhone.  There's not any **real** magic going on here ... it just seems to be a **very clean and very easy** to use device.

So now I'd like to take our internal project management application and create another user interface specifically targeted to iPhone.

I googled some sites and most of them seem very kool-aidish, not real meat or substance. I did see where you can use some additional Html attributes to get certain things to appear iPhonish as well as a User Interface library to help out with the rendering.

Do you know of any good sites or having any recommendations for getting started creating an iPhone web user interface using ASP.NET?  Is there any references out there that explain all the the Html tricks or syntax you can use that the iPhone/Safari will recognize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about webpages, yes it can be done.

See Aaron Rocks post here:[Rock the iPhone with ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/aaronlerch/archive/2008/06/08/rock-the-iphone-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)  (via [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode28IPhoneWithASPNETMVCEdition.aspx))

He's using MVC for it.

I've yet to try it, but it looks good.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

The [MVC 4 roadmap](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap) indicates that MVC 4 should have support for Mobile views.

Answer (score 3):

The apple [developer site](http://developer.apple.com/webapps/) is the best starting point.

You don't need to use a mac for development if you're just doing a web app and you're happy with a browser based interface.

I don't use ASP.NET myself, however there should be nothing special about using it for this, you just need to follow the guidelines for the HTML / javascript interface so it should be no different than using any other javascript library.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [IUI](http://code.google.com/p/iui/). 
It's simple to use and looks great. All you would need to do is modify your ASP pages to use it.

Answer (score 2):

In a way your question doesn't make sense. The browser (webkit, which is what the iphone uses, IE, FF, Safari) doesn't see what happens on the server, which is where the asp.net lives. So your question should be: what can I do to optimize my web page for a mobile phone, specifically iPhone? This was the first hit I [thought looked helpful](http://www.ehousestudio.com/blog/2008/01/24/how-your-website-will-look-on-the-iphone-and-ipod-touch/).